# Is this possible to calculate this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this possible to store the decimal type value in number column. 1/12 will be 0.083 and wants to store that in that column.

```
 create table test(number1 int,number2 int,number float)
 insert into test values(1,12,CAST(CAST(1/12 AS decimal(9,2)) AS float))
```

i have tried cast function but it not worked

Comment: It is better not to use FLOAT data type. It is imprecise data type. The DECIMAL(9,2) is better.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky: Depends on the use case. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Heinzi AMEN!  So tired of the default anti-float position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it.  The problem you are having is that `1 / 12` is `0`, because SQL Server does integer division.

Instead use `1.0 / 12`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4607bfb8512b1c3f7343e2dbb15a1670) is a db<>fiddle illustrating the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
insert into test values(1,12,CAST(CAST(1.0/12 AS decimal(9,3)) AS float));
```

Result:

```
 number1  number2  number 
 -------- -------- ------ 
 1        12       0.083
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f1f6f/1).

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are storing a `float`, you might be better off defining the value you are inserting as `float` in the first place:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.test (number1, number2, number)
VALUES(1,12,1e/12);
```

If you want exactly `0.083`, rather than `0.083~` then you should define `number` as a `decimal` and then insert a `decimal`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.test(number1 int,
                       number2 int,
                       number decimal(5,3));
INSERT INTO dbo.test (number1, number2, number)
VALUES(1,12,1./12);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=979f5b90f104c73de979924c83b7d9b5)